# How to check for specific type of an interface

Tags: c#, interface

Say I have this object

```
public class foo 
{
    Ibar data {get; set;}
}

public interface Ibar
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class bar : Ibar
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string a {get; set;}
}


public class bar2 : Ibar
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public DateTime b {get; set;}
}
```

Now I implement a method like this one here

```
public something Method(foo f)
{
    if(f.data is bar)
        Console.WriteLine(((bar)f.data).doSomething());
    else
        Console.WriteLine(((bar2)f.data).doSomething());
}

public string doSomething(this bar b)
{
    return b.a;
}

public string doSomething(this bar2 b)
{
    return b.b.ToString();
}
```

So far so good ([see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMbbeK)). Is there a way to make this part here more elegant? in particular if I have more than one implementations of `Ibar`, it gets messy...

```
    if(f.data is bar)
        Console.WriteLine(((bar)f.data).doSomething());
    else
        Console.WriteLine(((bar2)f.data).doSomething());
```

**UPDATE**

So `doSomething` should be an extension method. That's why it isn't defined in the interface. So in other words: Im not allowed to change the interface or their implementations.

Comment: That depends on your `doSomething`-method. If it really needs an instance of either `bar` or `bar2` you have to provide `data` casted to that specific class. But we don´t know if the interface `IBar` wouldn´t be feasible also, e.g. `DoSomething(IBar bar) { ... } `. From your current code `bar2` and `bar` don´t have much in common - at least nothing you could use in `DoSomething`.

Comment: What about you declare `doSomething` method at interface and provide the definition of this method in derived classes (`Bar` & `Bar2`). In that case, you should do only  `f.data.doSomething();` which returns the required value.

Comment: Does not look like the way OO works. The code should look like `f.data.dosomething();` and it's up to bar/bar2's job to implement the dosomething method.

Comment: you don't. `doSomething` should be a method in each of the implementations of the `IBar` interface.

Comment: Agreed with the other commenters that doSomething should be on the interface. If you've got a more concrete example where that wouldn't work then it would be worth updating the question.

Comment: @dlatikay agree on the method argument. The thing is, those "bar"'s are ViewModel implementations and apparently I should keep ViewModel's free from methods

Comment: @Baffour `bar` and `bar2` are ViewModels, and should if possible be free of code (except for the properties ofc). The `doSomething` is an extension method, with specific mapping

Comment: @rst I have added an answer where you won't be required to do if else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make dedicated extention class?

assuming you are doing so.

however you can achieve your goal with `dynamic`

```
public static class BarExtensions
{
  public static string Something(this Ibar b)
  {
      return doSomething((dynamic)b);
  }

  public static string doSomething( bar b)
  {
     return b.a;
  }

  public static string doSomething(bar2 b)
  {
     return b.b.ToString();
  }
}
```

so, you will required to call `Something` only, with Proper Type.

Here Type can be easily get by `.GetType()` of any object (so it won't be a problem)

Comment: thank you sir, I think this is the best answer and in my opinion the most elegant way. I didn't come up with using `dynamic`.

Comment: I just found the flaw in this implementation. You can't place the methods `doSomething(barX b)` in other classes....

Comment: @rst you mean to say you are trying to make `doSomething` method  in other class than `something` method ? if so.. why you want to do so? and what problem are you facing?

Comment: Yes. I have bar ViewModels, and bar ExtensionMethods, so for each barX there are 2 classes (the poco ViewModel and the ExtensionMethod class). Additionally there is the "Something" class, which should apply the corresponding "doSomething" method

Comment: @rst I afraid, I am not getting exact flow of your project.. but, if you keep this extension method and corresponding doSomething methods static and public, it should be doable. but I will not recommend to do it blindly, proper design is must if you don't want to make it ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the type checks in one place because this is a good candidate for polymorphism. Since both `bar` and `bar2` implement `Ibar`, you can change the definition of `doSomething` to the following.

```
public string doSomething(Ibar item)
{
    return item is bar ? ((bar)item).a : ((bar2)item).b.ToString();
}
```

Now when you want to display it, this is how you handle your foo:

```
public void Method(foo f)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.data);
}
```

You just pass in the `data` property because the `doSomething` will know what to do with it when it receives it.

**Update**
Based on your comment, I'm expanding the code to use pattern matching as I suggested. Consider the following

```
public string doSomething(Ibar item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case bar b:
            return b.a;
        case bar2 b:
            return b.b.ToString();
        case barX b:
            return b.X.ToString();
        default:
            return item.GetType().ToString(); // Just in case...
    }
}
```

where the definition of barX is

```
public class barX : Ibar
{
    public int id {get; set; }
    public object X {get; set; }
}
```

So whenever you add an implementation of Ibar, you cater for it in doSomething. All client code will remain unchanged because all they have to do is pass an Ibar to the `doSomething` method which uses pattern matching in the last example to determine what type the item is and it acts accordingly.

**Final Edit**

Seeing as you want to use overloads, you can use reflection but I don't know if that will qualify for your definition of elegant. In this case, it will not use switch statements and will find your methods as long as they are in the type this one is written in. Consider the following and change the defintion of my previously supplied DoSomething.

```
public static string ProcessThings(Ibar item)
{
    var theType = item.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(theType.Name);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethods()
        .Where(x => x.IsStatic && x.Name == "DoSomething" && x.ToString().Contains(theType.Name))
        .SingleOrDefault();

    var ret = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { item });

    return ret?.ToString();
}

public static string DoSomething(barX item)
{
    return "foo";
}

public static string DoSomething(bar2 item)
{
    return "bar";
}
```

This way, you call the `ProcessThings` method (renamed for brevity but it can still stay as DoSomething) and it will figure out which one of your overloads to call.

Comment: What if I have n different implementations of `barX`?

Comment: When you make the various implementations of it, you can modify the `doSomething` method with each new `barX` so that the calling code doesn't change. With the newer editions of C# you can use pattern matching, I didn't use that in my original answer because I didn't know which version of C# you're using

Comment: @rst I have updated my answer. Have a look if it meets your needs.

Comment: Your updated answer is just as ugly as my initial propositon (With `switch case`)

Comment: @rst test test answer

Comment: @rst If you not the difference between mine and yours, your switch case is happening to decide which overload of do something to call, mine is in a single DoSomething extension method which will be defined to act on the interface Ibar. Have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixEi6E) to see what I mean. The only other way I see is if you have a delegate that you pass to the extension method which it will then call but that might have it's own elegance issues.

Comment: I see what you mean and it makes sense, thank you. I was hoping on something like overload methods and then `doSomething((truetypeof(f.data))f.data)`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @rst I have updated my answer to use reflection. See the final edit section and I think that may suffice provided there is an implementation of DoSomething that matches the type given.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well you can play with [generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) like this:

```
public something Method<T>(T f) where T : IBar
{
    //Stuff here, where assures you f is always IBar
}
```

This should force the incoming parameter to be of the type you want.
This is the most elegant way I could think of.

Other are [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof) and other conditional statements, which would require more in-method code anyway (if, else and so on).

**EDIT:**
Since OP seems having a hard time to understand I wrote a fully working code sample with Microsoft Unit Testing result.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
namespace UnitTests_ALL
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnrelatedTests
    {


        [TestMethod]
        public void InterfaceTest()
        {
            bar x = new bar { result = "Hi bar it's " };
            bar2 xx = new bar2 { beforeResult = DateTime.Now };

            Console.WriteLine(Method(x));
            Console.WriteLine(Method(xx));

        }

        public string Method<T>(T f) where T : Ibar
        {
            return f.result;
        }

    }

    public class foo
    {
        public foo(Ibar fooBar)
        {
            data = fooBar;
        }
        Ibar data { get; set; }
    }
    public interface Ibar
    {
        int id { get; set; }
        string result { get; set; }
    }

    public class bar : Ibar
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }
    }


    public class bar2 : Ibar
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime beforeResult
        {
            set { result = value.ToString(); }
        }
        public string result { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {

        public static string doSomething(this bar b)
        {
            return b.result;
        }

        public static string doSomething(this bar2 b)
        {
            return b.result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me, I need specific code that doesn't implement the interface, else I don't know exactly what to do

Comment: You don't need to check if is bar or bar2. You are passing an interface, that doesn't make sense before everything. Interfaces are made to pass something that works universally. By using my code you are sure that whatever you will pass into the method will work with the methods defined into the IBar interface.

What you don't know to do?

Comment: @LiquidCore the OP is calling different methods depending on which bar is passed. Using a generic will still not access the additional (non Ibar) properties.

Comment: This is one single method, where do I distinguish on how to return the string?

Comment: @rst Implement in the interface property to return (es string c) then in bar and bar2 assign to c the return result. That's what interfaces are for.

Comment: @LiquidCore I specifically do not want to implement that in bar and bar2 for very good reasons.

Comment: @rst check it now

Comment: @LiquidCore I don't have a hard time understanding, you don't understood the setup: bar and bar2 shall not be changed from the question. They are as they are,  I can't change that

Comment: @rst You never specified that. You asked a more elegant way to do things and I gave you what you asked for. If you change the rules later and not even writing them  what do you expect? We aren't wizards. Your only update refers to keeping doSomething as an extension.

Comment: @rst I don't see it anywhere